# Extracting a dictionary from sparse csv file

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary

I have a sparsely populated excel file I want to extract two columns into a dictionary in C#. I have tried the following. This fails when it reads the blank lines. Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same. I don't care about any other values here. Just a mapping of `AR ID` to `AR Type` would do.

```
     public class Table
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _ARID_ARTypeValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private string _arId;

        public Table(string arId)
        {
            _arId = arId;
        }

        public void AddValue(string key, string value)
        {
            _ARID_ARTypeValues.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public static IDictionary ParseCsvFile(StreamReader reader)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Table> tables = new Dictionary<string, Table>();

        // First line contains column names.
        var columnNames = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
        for (int i = 1; i < columnNames.Length; ++i)
        {
            var columnName = columnNames[i];
            var ntable = new Table(columnName);
            if ((columnName == "AR ID") || (columnName == "AR Type"))
            {
                tables.Add(columnName, ntable);
            }
        }

        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            var columns = line.Split(',');

            for (int j = 1; j < columns.Length; ++j)
            {
                var table = tables[columnNames[j]];
                table.AddValue(columns[0], columns[j]);
            }
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        return tables;
    }
```

[image: sample csv]

Comment: If it fails on blank lines why not just check if the line is blank before processing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a CSV library, like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) and read the csv file with that.

```
Dictionary<string, string> arIdToArTypeMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using (var sr = File.OpenText("test.csv"))
{
    var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration
    {
        SkipEmptyRecords = true
    };

    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(sr, csvConfiguration))
    {
        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            string arId = csvReader.GetField("AR ID");
            string arType = csvReader.GetField("AR Type");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(arType))
            {
                arIdToArTypeMapping.Add(arId, arType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library, to read the csv and convert them to dictionary as simple as with few lines of code shown below

```
using (var parser = new ChoCSVReader("Dict1.csv")
    .WithField("AR_ID", 7)
    .WithField("AR_TYPE", 8)
    .WithFirstLineHeader(true)
    .Configure(c => c.IgnoreEmptyLine = true)
    )
{
    var dict = parser.ToDictionary(item => item.AR_ID, item => item.AR_TYPE);
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " " + kvp.Value);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.